# Unusual "(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'" error when conductin KNN alogrithm

Tags: r

I'm conducting a KNN algorithm on R. I have three datasets. I've been working on my code here's what I have:

```
library(stats)
library(class)

#load up train and testing files
train1<-read.table("train1.txt",header=FALSE) 
test1<-read.table("test1.txt",header=FALSE)

#convert inputs into matrix
train = matrix(train1, byrow = T, ncol=3)
test = matrix(test1, byrow = T, ncol=3)

#load the classes in the training data
cl1a<-read.table("classes1.txt",header = FALSE)
clas=matrix(cl1a,byrow=T,ncol=1)

#set k 
kk = 2

#run knn
kn1 = knn(train, test, clas, k=kk, prob=TRUE)
```

After running the last line I get the error message:

> Error in knn(train, test, clas, k = kk, prob = TRUE) : 
>     (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

I've read somewhere else that this can be fixed by converting tables into matrix, but I fixed that on my code as you can see.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe try using dataframes instead of matrices. Can't really see what's wrong. Where does a `traceback()` call point at(to)?

Comment: Also why noy just use `as.matrix`?

Comment: When using traceback I get: `> traceback()
1: knn(train, test, clas, k = kk, prob = TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks! I used as.matrix and it worked. Just so I know, what is the difference between as.matrix and matrix? I litterally replaced one for the other and it worked. Here's my new code:

`[... ]#convert inputs into matrix
train = as.matrix(train1, byrow = T, ncol=3)
test = as.matrix(test1, byrow = T, ncol=3)

#load the classes in the training data
cl1a<-read.table("classes1.txt",header = FALSE)
clas=as.matrix(cl1a,byrow=T,ncol=1)


#set k 
kk = 1

#run knn
kn1 = knn(train, test, clas, k=kk, prob=TRUE)`

Comment: `as.matrix` does the necessary transformations for you without dropping any values. This is just a snippet of an answer, you could read more on these via `?matrix` and `?as.matrix`.

Comment: I've added a kind of detailed answer.

Comment: please note that you can accept and/or upvote an answer if it helps solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `as.matrix` as I suggested in my comments above. Here's why:

```
str(matrix(iris,byrow=T,ncol=5))
```

As you can see this produces a list.

```
List of 5
 $ : num [1:150] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ : num [1:150] 3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ : num [1:150] 1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ : num [1:150] 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 1 5
```

`as.matrix` on the other hand produces a matrix. 
**Now why the error anyways?**
From `?knn` we can see that it accepts matrices or dataframes:

> train
>       matrix or data frame of training set cases.
>       test
>       matrix or data frame of test set cases. 
>      A vector will be interpreted as a row vector for a single case

This explains why we have the error:

> Error in knn(train, test, clas, k = kk, prob = TRUE) : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

The safe thing to do is to either use `as.data.frame` or `as.matrix`